# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, Does anyone know how to get this weird comment feature?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Previously I used to have IntelliJ looking like this
[image]

Now if you look at those gray comments for example ": Promise<...>" or ": EmbedBuilder" that is what I'm talking about.

After I reinstalled my IntelliJ IDEA I don't know what it is called and how to get it anymore.

If someone knows please let me know.

Comment: It is called Inlay Hints. Go to _Settings -> Editor -> Inlay Hints_ and enable it back for your language.

Comment: @Yann39 thank you so much for your reply and help. I appreciate it a lot!